# Nginx access.logの$time_localを日本時間表示にする方法

Tags: nginx

Nginxのaccess.logに出力される$time_localはデフォルトではUTC+0で表示されるようです。
これを日本時間での出力に変更したいです。

現在の$time_local出力は`[28/Feb/2016:01:46:24 +0000]`となっています。

ネットやNginxポケットリファレンスをみても設定方法をみつけられませんでした。
もし日本時間に設定する方法知っていいましたらご教授お願いします。

OSはAmazon Linuxです。

Answer (score 1):

OS のタイムゾーンが Asia/Tokyo になっていないのではないでしょうか。
OS のタイムゾーンが Asia/Tokyo なら、$time_local は +9 時間になります。
タイムゾーンを Asia/Tokyo に変更するか、環境変数 TZ='Asia/Tokyo' で nginx を起動すればいいと思います。
設定方法は Linux ディストリビューションによって変わりますが、RHEL/CentOS 系であれば、タイムゾーンの変更は、

```
# cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo /etc/localtime
```

でできると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。環境変数を設定してnginxを再起動してみましたが、やはり+0となってしまいます。また、`cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo /etc/localtime`も試してみましたがうまくいきませんでした。

Comment: こちらで確認したバージョンは amzn-ami-hvm-2015.09.2.x86_64-gp2 (ami-59bdb937), nginx-1.8.1-1.26.amzn1.x86_64 です。
access_log は +9 時間になりました。
「127.0.0.1 - - [28/Feb/2016:17:15:11 +0900] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3770 "-" "curl/7.40.0" "-"」